# Where can I see the list of built-in wavelet functions that I can pass to scipy.signal.cwt?

Tags: python, scipy, signal-processing, wavelet

`scipy.signal.cwt`'s documentation [says](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.signal.cwt.html):

> scipy.signal.cwt(data, wavelet, widths)
>
> wavelet : function
>   Wavelet function, which should take 2 arguments. The first argument is the number of points that the returned vector
>   will have (len(wavelet(width,length)) == length). The second is a
>   width parameter, defining the size of the wavelet (e.g. standard
>   deviation of a gaussian). See ricker, which satisfies these
>   requirements.wavelet : function Wavelet function, which should take 2 arguments.

Beyond `scipy.signal.ricket`, what are the other built-in wavelet functions that I can pass to scipy.signal.cwt?

I see in  [scipy / scipy / signal / wavelets.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.13.0/scipy/signal/wavelets.py)

```
__all__ = ['daub', 'qmf', 'cascade', 'morlet', 'ricker', 'cwt']
```

and looking at the arguments of each of those wavelet functions, only `ricket` seems to work with `scipy.signal.cwt(data, wavelet, widths)` (as only `ricker` takes precisely 2 arguments).

Comment: "Beyond scipy.signal.ricket, what are the other built-in wavelet functions that I can pass to scipy.signal.cwt?"  There aren't any.  http://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/18104/29

Comment: @endolith Thanks for the link! (nice to see DSP migration consistency)

Comment: Yeah why isn't this question on DSP.SE?

Comment: @endolith got migrated here, not sure why. Well at least it didn't get closed.

Comment: I guess because it's about a specific software, not theory.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I asked the [question on the SciPy Users List](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2014-May/035727.html) , answer 1:

> I found the module for CWT quite confusing, so I rolled my own:
>
> https://github.com/Dapid/fast-pycwt
>
> It is built for speed (I got my running time from 4 h down to 20 min).
>   It is not thoroughly tested, and it is limited to single and double;
>   but for me it is in a "good enough" state.

Answer 2:

> You might also find my version useful:
>
> https://github.com/aaren/wavelets
>
> I also found scipy wavelets confusing. My version includes a faster
>   cwt that can take wavelets expressed in either frequency or time.
>
> I found it more intuitive to have wavelet functions that take
>   time/frequency and width as arguments rather than the present method
>   (I prefer thinking in real space rather than sample space).
>
> Presently, the morlet wavelet that comes with scipy,
>   `scipy.signal.wavelets.morlet`, cannot be used as input to cwt. This
>   is unfortunate I think.
>
> Additionally, the present cwt doesn't allow complex output. This
>   doesn't make a difference for ricker but wavelet functions are complex
>   in general.
>
> My modified 'cwt' method is here:
>
> https://github.com/aaren/wavelets/blob/master/wavelets.py#L15
>
> It can accept wavelet functions defined in time or frequency space,
>   uses fftconvolve, and allows complex output.
>
> My background on this is based on a reading of Torrence and Compo:
>
> Torrence and Compo, 'A Practical Guide to Wavelet Analysis' (BAMS,
>   1998)
>
> http://paos.colorado.edu/research/wavelets/
>
> hope that helps a bit,
>
> aaron

Comment: As the author of the first one, I recommend the second, unless you really need the speed.